# Why is my Date() variable being changed and is there a way to work around it?

Tags: javascript, date, variables

https://jsfiddle.net/meeky333/zhgybqou/8/

In my jsfiddle I have a 1st, 2nd and 3rd date. I have assigned `1 = new Date()` and then assigned `2 = 1` and then `3 = 2`, except I set the hours of 2 using `.setHours()`.

I understand that `.setHours()` will not only return the date in an int form. But it will update the object it came from... But it has come from `mySecondDate`. So why is `myFirstDate` being changed also?

How do I make `myThirdDate` stay the same but keep the value of `myFirstDate` the same as it was.

NOTE: `mySecondDate` is just a throw away variable, It was just for illustration purposes.

Comment: `a = b` does not *clone* an object. Just sets a second variable pointing at the same object.

Comment: I find that odd that it does that. Makes sense though. Is there a general way to clone a variable?

Comment: No, no general way. Dates are cloned via the constructor `newDate = new Date(oldDate)` but other objects might or might not have a copy constructor. They might or might not expose a way to clone. [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) can work for some objects but not all objects. For example it will clone a Date, also a plain object like `{a: 1, b: true, c: "hello"}` but it will not clone any functions, e.g. `{name: "fred", getName: function() { return this.name } }` will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are pointing all to the same Object. You could copy the date like this:

```
var myControlDate = new Date();
var myFirstDate = new Date();
var mySecondDate = new Date(myFirstDate);
var myThirdDate = new Date(mySecondDate.setHours(3, 3, 3, 3));


console.log("myControlDate: " + myControlDate);
console.log("myFirstDate: " + myFirstDate);
console.log("mySecondDate: " + mySecondDate);
console.log("myThirdDate: " + myThirdDate);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is helpful. It's a good way to fix my issue. So instead of assigning my variable another variable. I can create a new Date that just has the same values as my first Date(). Very clever. Thank you :)